# SSRS using iff when dividing

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I need to incorporate and iif statment in my expression. What I want to do is say if a field value = 0 then Fields!example1.value/Fields!example2.value else Fields!example1.value/Fields!example3.value. I hope that is clear in what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate twice in order to keep your report safe of division by zero erros.

Try this:

```
=iif(
Fields!Field2.Value=0,
    iif(Fields!Field3.Value=0
    ,0
    ,Fields!Field1.Value/iif(Fields!Field3.Value=0,1,Fields!Field3.Value)),
Fields!Field1.Value/iif(Fields!Field2.Value=0,1,Fields!Field2.Value)
)
```

Comment: ok thank you. Here is the statement that I got to work                           `=iif(Fields!COVERAGE.value = 0, Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value) / (ReportItems!CalculatedUnitsSold1.value), Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value) / Sum(Fields!CalculatedUnitsSold.Value))`                                                                            can you please incorporate the divide by zero issue into my code.