# Divide by zero SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I need help in adding logic to the following code to handle divide by zero

```
=iif(Fields!COVERAGE.value = 0, Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value) / (ReportItems!CalculatedUnitsSold1.value), Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value) / Sum(Fields!CalculatedUnitsSold.Value))
```

Comment: I answered you in a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33265047/2647648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=iif(Fields!COVERAGE.value = 0,
Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value)/
   iif((ReportItems!CalculatedUnitsSold1.value)<>0,
   (ReportItems!CalculatedUnitsSold1.value),1),
Sum(Fields!CalculatedTotalIncidents.Value) / 
   iif(Sum(Fields!CalculatedUnitsSold.Value)<>0,
Sum(Fields!CalculatedUnitsSold.Value),1))
```

Comment: That failed out. Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart'

Comment: @D4TAM4X: I've update the expression in my answer check it, In both cases if denominator is 0, the expression will return de numerator value. Example: `6/0 = 6`. You can modify this as required.

Comment: @D4TAM4X: Nice! In that case you can select my answer as correct by clicking on the correct symbol below the zero at left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be very simple if you implement a function in custom code of report

```
function div (a as integer, b as integer) as decimal
 if (a > 0 ) then
   div = a/b
 else
   div = 0
 end if
end function
```

Then call this function in your report. You also can extend this function base on your specific business rule.

Hope this help.